# want to generate coupon code 5 digit number

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

i want to create a coupon code generator by using SQL database but i don't know how to generate 1000 of random number without repeating them. so can  someone help me it's important. thanks

Comment: Is it sqlite or sql server? those are 2 different things.

Comment: To Zohar Peled, I was working with SQL but for some reason it wasn't working, so I start using SQLlite.

Comment: Do you need to select a single value or multiple values each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records in a relational database tables are unordered by nature.
therefor, you can simply create a table that has all the values between `@First` and `@Last` (0 and 9999 in your case), and then use a random order by when selecting from that table. you can also use a simple int in the database table and just format it when you select the data from the table.

Since my main database is Sql server, and I have no experience with sqlite, I will use Sql Server syntax in my code example, and leave it up to you to find the sqllite equivalent.

First, create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl 
(
    IntValue int PRIMARY KEY,
    IsUsed bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

Then, populate it with numbers between 0 and 9999:

```
;With CTE AS (
    SELECT 0 As IntValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  IntValue + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE IntValue + 1 < 10000
)

INSERT INTO Tbl (IntValue)
SELECT IntValue
FROM CTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then, you want to select multiple values each time, so I would write a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_GetCouponCodes
(
    @Number int = 5 -- or whatever number is default
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @UsedValues AS TABLE
  (
      IntValue int
  )

  BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  INSERT INTO @UsedValues 
  SELECT TOP(@Number) IntValue
  FROM Tbl
  WHERE IsUsed = 0
  ORDER BY NEWID()

  UPDATE Tbl
  SET IsUsed = 1
  FROM Tbl 
  INNER JOIN 
  @UsedValues uv ON(Tbl.IntValue = uv.IntValue)

  SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(IntValue as varchar), 5)
  FROM @UsedValues 

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  END CATCH
END
```

Then, when ever you want to generate coupons, simply execute the stored procedure with the number of coupons you want:

```
EXEC stp_GetCouponCodes 10;
```

[See working fiddle example here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35988/1)

Comment: Zohar peled, thanks bro thanks for the  help.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses a quick method to generate 100 random 5-character strings based on the alphabet provided. You'll still need to perform duplicate checking, but this should get you started.

```
DECLARE @Quantity INT = 1000
DECLARE @Alphabet VARCHAR(100) = '0123456789'
DECLARE @Length INT = LEN(@Alphabet)
DECLARE @Top INT = SQRT(@Quantity) + 1
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (@Top) *
    FROM sys.objects
)
SELECT TOP (@Quantity)
    SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Length + 1, 1)
    + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Length + 1, 1)
    + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Length + 1, 1)
    + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Length + 1, 1)
    + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Length + 1, 1)
    AS [Code]
FROM CTE X
    CROSS JOIN CTE Y
```

Comment: but is this for SQL server or SQLlite.

Comment: I tested it for SQL server. May have to change approach for the CTE to generate the 100 characters - I don't remember if sys.objects is available in sql-lite. Will update in a few mins.

Comment: thanks anyway though.

Comment: ok, won't update it then...sorry missed the sqllite tag